# Is there a way to reset the document scale when returning through the browser history?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, adaptive-design

There is a mobile version of the site on the same domain as the main version. It is possible to disable the mobile version (enable the desktop version). The problem is that the browser remembers the scale of the pages viewed and if you switch from the mobile version to the desktop version and go back, an enlarged page is displayed.
We tried to use initial-scale, but it no longer helps, because The browser saves the scale that was in the mobile version.

Is there a way to somehow reset the scaling or the only way out is a separate subdomain for the mobile version? (Then the pages for different versions will differ and the browser will remember its scale for each version).

A short video (0:14) with an illustration of the problem using github.com as an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4TxxiaDw3c&feature=youtu.be

Comment: If this browser behavior I don't think you can do anything, but maybe there is a hack. Maybe that's why some sites have mobile version on different (sub) domain.

Comment: It seems like this ... We tried to hack: set the maximum-scale to 1, and then delete it using JS, but this does not work with every browser

Comment: If you have solution but it don't work in every browser maybe there is no other way. Check how Wikipedia did his mobile page.